# Profiling MPI+Cuda

Tags: cuda, mpi, profiler, openmpi

I'm developing a MPI+cuda project and I've tried to profile my app with nvvp and nvprof but, in both cases it doesn't give a profile. The app works completely fine, but no profile is generated.

```
nvprof mpirun -np 2 MPI_test
[...]
======== Warning: No CUDA application was profiled, exiting
```

I tried with simpleMPI cuda example with the same result.

I'm using CUDA 5.0 in a 580 GTX and openMPI 1.7.3 (featured, not release yet because I'm testing the CUDA-aware option)

Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you try to profile under linux? Because on linux os I have to pass to complete absolute path to the application to nvprof. If I don't pass it, than I get the same warning like you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpirun` itself is not a CUDA application. You have to run the profiler like `mpirun -np 2 nvprof MPI_test`. But you also have to make sure that each instance of `nvprof` (two instances in that case) is writing to a different output file. Open MPI exports the `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK` environment variable that gives the process rank in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. This could be used in just another wrapper, e.g. `wrap_nvprof`:

```
#!/bin/bash
nvprof -o profile.$OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK $*
```

This should be run like `mpirun -n 2 ./wrap_nvprof executable <arguments>` and after it has finished there should be two output files with profile information: `profile.0` for rank 0 and `profile.1` for rank 1.

**Edit:** There is an example `nvprof` wrapper script that does the same in a more graceful way and that handles both Open MPI and MVAPICH2 in the `nvvp` documentation. A version of the script is reproduced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12057513/1374437) to a question that yours is more or less a duplicate of.

Comment: I had already tested the script in the answer you say. But the problem was the path to the executable, nvprof needs ./MPI_test so

`mpirun -n 2 ./wrap_nvprof /path_to_executable
 <arguments>`
is the correct way.
Thank you very much!

Comment: It depends on how `nvprof` executes the binary. Relative paths, e.g. `./executable`, should probably work too.

Comment: Yes, of course, I mean, `nvprof` needs a `./` or `/` before executable, at least in my case.